# PrestaShop 1.7 An error occurred while sending the message, please try again

Tags: prestashop

In my PrestaShop in Advanced Parameters E-mail e send tests messages with success.

But in my contact page email form when I send a email I receive a message

> an error occurred while sending the message, please try again.

My troubleshooting atttempt:

> In line 418 in the file "modules/contactform/contactform.php"
>   $this→context→controller→errors[] = $this→trans('An error occurred while sending the message, please try again.', array(), 'Modules.Contactform.Shop');

I replace by this code:

```
$this→context→controller→errors[] = $errorMessage = error_get_last()['message'];
```

Then I sent an email in my Contacts page and I got the following error:

> Undefined property: stdClass::$id_shop

How can I resolve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem...

You must to edit contactform.tpl, and add this before the submit button :

```
<style>
input[name=url] {
display: none !important;
}
</style>
<input type="text" name="url" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$token}" />
```

Regards,

PS : remove your old modifications on contactform.php

Steve T.

Comment: you dont need the style if you use <input type="hidden" name="url" value=""/>

Answer (score 0):

Current version: 1.7.3.1

Modules > Contactform > Configure

Receive customers' messages by email: (y)

themes/used theme name/modules/contactform/views/templates/widget/contactform.tpl

paste this code on top of the send button

```
<input type="text" name="url" value="" class="hidden"> 
<input type="hidden" name="token" value="{$token}">
```

[image]

Comment: didn't help in 1.7.4.4

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in modules/contactform/contactform.php function sendMail()
there is a condition on line cca 520:

```
} elseif (
        $url !== '' 
        || empty($serverToken)  
        || $clientToken !== $serverToken
        || $clientTokenTTL < time()
    ) {
        $this->context->controller->errors[] = $this->trans(
            'An error occurred while sending the message, please try again.',
            [],
            'Modules.Contactform.Shop'
        );
```

because $serverToken is false, this always throws an error. (serverToken is generated on widget rendering, but cookie is not saved, so on form submisiion, when page is loading it is false).

Solutions are:

a/ commenting this whole condition (inputs in tpl will not be needed then)

b/ save the tokens generated in createNewToken() and alter the condition (here you will need input fields in tpl as mentioned above).

(prestashop 1.7.7.4)